# Проблема с обратным слешем в Python при указании путей!

Tags: python

У меня возникла проблема с `\.`

При указании пути к файлу `C:\Users\кк\Dekstop\games` вылезает ошибка

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\кк\Desktop\games", line 54, in module
     os.startfile(r"C:\Users\кк\Dekstop\games")
 FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: 
 'C:\\Users\\кк\\Dekstop\\games'
```

Comment: `/` not `\\` 4 символа нужно...

Comment: games — файл? Или каталог? Нужен путь к файлу.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, ошибаетесь, под Windows путь разделяется обратным слешем.

Comment: возможно проблема в русском названии директории.

Comment: @insolor, любым. Но при копировании из проводника там именно обратные.

Comment: @insolor Может быть, я на маке, так что думал, что путь на винде надо так же писать.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, скажем так: винде все равно какой будет слеш (хотя основной вариант - обратный слеш), поэтому если система не находит путь, то изменение слеша на противоположный результат не изменит.